# Why is my cron daemon is being killed every few minutes?

Tags: debian, cron, openvz, service, strace

As of about a week ago, my cron daemon refuses to stay running. I'm using Debian 6 x64 on an OpenVZ virtual machine. Running something like `pgrep cron` shows that the daemon isn't running. I start the service with `service cron start` or `/etc/init.d/cron start` and it launches, but it disappears from the running process list after a few minutes (varying anywhere between 1 - 30 minutes before the process is killed again).

Using `strace -f service cron start`, I can see that the process is being killed for some reason:

```
nanosleep({60, 0},  <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
```

There's nothing relevant in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/auth.log`, or `/var/log/kern.log` to explain why the the process is dying. The system has at least 800 MB of free memory, and `cat /proc/loadavg` returns `0.22 0.13 0.04` so resources shouldn't be the issue. With `cron` running, `free -m` reports:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        211        812          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        211        812
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I also tried removing and reinstalling the `cron` package using `apt-get`.

***Update:*** I initially thought the problem was a resource issues. I erased my entire VPS and started from a fresh Debian image. There is now nothing else running on the system, but even from a clean install my cron daemon is still being killed at random.

What else should I check? How do I find out what's killing my `crond`?

Comment: For completeness, what's the output of `free -m` (concerned that your 500MB free is happening after it's killed and you have no swap) and is this a physical or virtual machine? If virtual, what hypervisor?

Comment: Ah, good point. It's an OpenVZ VM. I updated the question.

Comment: I'm having the exactly same issue after reinstalling a VPS under OpenVZ with vePortal, Debian 5 x86_64 and DirectAdmin. In my case I have no control of the host because it's on a VPS hosting provider. The counters at `/proc/user_beancounters` doesn't reset after virtual host reboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I have stumbled on a workaround. For some reason, `cron` is only being killed (presumably by the host) if it's running in daemon mode. If launched with `cron -f`, the process persists. So, I created a simple script to launch it in the foreground (and continually relaunch it in the unlikely event that it does get killed):

```
#!/bin/bash -u
while [ 1 ]; do
        logger -i -t cronrestart -p cron.warn "Launching cron daemon"
        cron -f
        logger -i -t cronrestart -p cron.warn "Cron daemon killed"
done
logger -i -t cronrestart -p cron.warn "Quitting"
```

Then I start this launcher script via `nohup cronrestart >/dev/null &` so it runs in the background. Cron has been running for a week so far this way without being killed.

I suppose the next step would be to [try making the launcher script start itself in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168781/how-to-include-nohup-inside-a-bash-script) to better simulate the daemon mode of `cron`.

Answer (score 4):

Look at `/proc/user_beancounters`, more specifically, at the `failcnt` column.

For all the non-zero entries, you'll need to increase the `barrier`/`limit` accordingly, it's probably just OpenVZ killing your processes for hitting them.

Here is a description of each column: http://wiki.openvz.org/Proc/user_beancounters

> For accountable parameters, the field held shows the current counter
>   for the container (resource “usage”), and the field maxheld shows the
>   counter's maximum for the last accounting period. The accounting
>   period is usually the lifetime of the container.
>
> The field failcnt shows the number of refused “resource allocations”
>   for the whole lifetime of the process group.
>
> The barrier and limit fields are resource control settings. For some
>   parameters, only one of them may be used, for some parameters — both.
>   These fields may specify limits or guarantees, and the exact meaning
>   of them is parameter-specific. Description of each parameter in UBC
>   parameters contains information about the difference between the
>   barrier and the limit for the parameter.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. Most things look in line to me, except I see `privvmpages` has failed about 4 million times since the start of the accounting period. :-) I stopped and restarted my VM and the failcounts didn't reset -- so I don't know how long my accounting period is (since the VM was created?). However, I'm not sure if this is the cause of my cron mystery. Shouldn't I see one of the failcounts increase after each death of crond?

Comment: If it answers your question, please click the green hollow tick on the left of my answer to accept it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I was in a comment and was premature in my use of the Enter key. :-)

Comment: Heh, fair enough :-) In my experience `failcnt`s definitely reset after a VM restarts, so I'm not sure why yours didn't. `failcnt` measures the number of times the allocations were *refused* (e.g. if you write a C program to `malloc()` memory, if that calls fails, then only `failcnt` will increment). OpenVZ may have killed your application because it needed to maintain a different one (e.g. it may judge that killing `crond` would allow all other applications to function correctly, so it's most optimal to kill it).

Comment: Ah, okay, so it may have sent the kill signal to `crond` in order to _avoid_ "failure" (because killing it would allow another process's memory allocation request to proceed)? Good thing OpenVZ is there to save the day ;-)

Comment: Precisely, the kernel can cheat by allocating memory to anyone who asks, then just killing the process it feels would be best so the rest can use their allocated share. Indeed! :-)

Comment: While this initially was a possibility, I don't think this is the case. I erased the VPS, installed a fresh copy of Debian and ran `apt-get` to `update` and `upgrade` the packages, and even with a clean install like this the problem persists. I initially suspected something in the `cron` APT package changed recently, but [Debian's change log](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-116/changelog) shows the last modification was in Nov 2010. I'm back to square one.

Comment: `SIGKILL` is the strongest kill signal that can be issued. Are you sure you don't have a script on a host that is accidentally terminating `crond` processes (processes within VEs will appear as processes on the host, under a normal `ps`). If not, how about the logs on the host? Anything there? `dmesg`?

Comment: This is a hosted VPS where I have no control over the host.